# Compile Time Hashing C++0x

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, hash

Using GCC 4.4 (generally the max available for Android and IOS) is there a way to do compile time hashing of strings.

We have a resource manager that maps string keys to resources.  While the lookup is fast the hashing and string creation is slow.  Something like:

```
 ResourcesManager::get<Texture>("someKey");
```

Spends a lot of time allocating the string "someKey" and then hashing it.

I'm wondering if there is a trick I can use to hash it at compile time.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter of `get`?  To avoid allocation, use `char const*`.

Comment: If the key is known at compile time, why don't you just use an `enum`?

Comment: smoching is right. why would you complicate your life performing compile-time hashing while you could use a simple enum like: `ResourcesManager::get<Texture>(Resources::SomeKey)`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I don't think the address of the literal is guaranteed to be the same for different instantiations of the same character sequence.

Comment: While for just resources enum is fine.  Some resource reference keys come from files, those should be hashed once instead of every use.  The bigger usage comes from rendering routines accessing Shader uniforms.  The lookup table for uniforms by string key.  This would benefit from compile time hashing.  You can't really enum this as the uniform locations are not consistent across hardware.  

With all that said, the business logic of the codebase is akin to scripting.  Keeping the lookup general case rather than coupled with an even growing enum seems smarter (for now).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to implement the right hashing algorithm, but this could work using C++11's constexpr functions:

```
#include <iostream>

// Dummy hashing algorithm. Adds the value of every char in the cstring.
constexpr unsigned compile_time_hash(const char* str) {
    // Modify as you wish
    return (*str == 0) ? 0 : (*str + compile_time_hash(str + 1));
}   

int main() {
    unsigned some_hash = compile_time_hash("hallou");
    std::cout << some_hash << std::endl;
}
```

Then you could have an overload of `ResourcesManager::get` which takes the result of `compile_time_hash`(an unsigned, in this case).

This obviously depends on which hashing algorithm you're applying. Implementing something like SHA* using constexpr will be pretty painful.

Note that you require GCC >= 4.6 or clang >= 3.1 in order to use constexpr.

Comment: Perhaps to help clarify: constexpr functions have a very strict form and cannot use loops. That's why hashing is quite difficult. _I also find it very odd to forbid loops and whatnot yet to permit recursion_

Comment: This prompted me to read up on constexpr which I admit I had not yet heard of.  Other than profiling (valgrind, gprof, etc) is there a way to verify if the constexpr is indeed evaluated at compile time?

Comment: Sorry.  This can't work.  GCC 4.4 does not support constexpr...
http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Comment: @Halsafar oh sorry, I didn't notice that you were using this in gcc 4.4. Well, this can be useful for those who are trying to achieve this in C++11.

Comment: For future reference.  XCode is currently able to compile this.  It appears to either ignore constexpr or is happy to take it in.  Android is still oin GCC 4.4 so it is not able to.  However google does provide GCC 4.6 sources.  Trying to compile them now.

Comment: Now that both IOS and Android include GCC 4.6 and constexpr works, this solution is perfect.

Comment: @Halsafar Glad to hear that :D. You can have a look at the constexpr md5 function I implemented about a week ago if you want to: https://github.com/mfontanini/Programs-Scripts/blob/master/constexpr_hashes/md5.h

Answer (score 2):

In order to do compile-time hashing, all your keys will need to be compile-time constants.

The usual way of indexing with compile-time constants is not to use strings, but to use an enumeration type. This has the advantage of not requiring hashing at all, since the constants are sequential and can index an array directly.

```
enum KeyType
{
    someKey,
    someOtherKey
};

ResourcesManager::get<Texture>(someKey);
```

If there's a need to get the key as a string, just keep a table of strings that can be indexed by the enumeration constants.

```
static char * keyNames = 
{
    "someKey",
    "someOtherKey"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always compile a program to hash your strings and output suitable sourcecode...

Myself, I'm not actually hashing the strings, I just enumerate the items and output a header file with the enumeration. Nice and easy, no collisons etc.